# How to install wallpapers?

Tags: 16.04, screensaver

Is there a simple way to install wallpapers in Linux? Not wallpaper packages but single wallpapers? How the installation works? In Windows, I point to the picture directory (in Appearance>Screensaver window) and select the picture file and do OK. How this procedure goes in Linux (once I download a picture file in some directory)?

Comment: Unless you tell us what desktop environment you're currently using, nobody will be able to tell you the exact steps : )
If you don't know, you could try opening a terminal and running the following command:

echo $DESKTOP_SESSION

Answer (score 3):

You can select any picture, right-click it and from the context menu select *Set as Wallpaper*. Alternatively you can select a custom wallpaper as follows.

#### 16.04

1. Select *System Settings* -> *Appearance* -> *Look* tab -> *Wallpapers*.
2. Under the Wallpapers section press the **+** button to add a new custom wallpaper image.

   [image]
3. Browse to the directory containing the custom wallpaper to be added, select a custom image, and click the *Open* button.

#### 18.04

Change the wallpaper from *Settings* → *Background* → *Picture* tab → select a picture → press *Select* button.

#### 20.04

Change  the wallpaper from *Settings* → *Background* → *Add Picture*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Ubuntu 17.10 (that means your desktop environment is Gnome), you could also add your pictures to the folder "Pictures" (inside your *Home* folder), then go to your system settings, select "background", then "background" again, there will be three different tabs to choose, "wallpapers" (these are pre-installed), "pictures" and the last one "colors", every picture inside your "Pictures" folder will be automatically added to the second section, "pictures".
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmO3S.png)